# python function with argument list

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I want to define a function, to find out the index of a list which satisfies some condition. But it always have some error：

```
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Below is my code

```
def find_index(x,*arr):
    for i in len(arr):
        if abs(i-x) < 1e-5:
            j = arr.index(i)
            return j
```

How do I specify arr is a list or numpy array? (Sorry, I do not know how to format the code in this editor)

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The (first) problem is `for i in len(arr)`.  `len(arr)` returns an integer which isn't iterable.  You *might* be tempted to use a `range(len(arr))`, but don't give in.  There are better options!  We can keep track of the index of the value as we iterate.  Generally, this function would probably look something like:

```
def find_index(x, arr):
    for i, val in enumerate(arr):
        if abs(val - x) < 1.e-5:
            return i
```

Now you can call this on *any* iterable.  e.g.:

```
find_index(5, [1, 2, 3, 5, 60])  # passing a list
find_index(5, (0, 5+1e-6, 10))  # passing a tuple
```

Comment: Just to clarify the use of `enumerate`: `arr.index(i)` is wasteful if you just want to know the index of the already found element.

Comment: Thank you very much. Learn a lot from you.

Answer (score 0):

You can Try to like :

```
   l=len(arr)
   for i in range(l)
```

`i` returns is integer value .integer value  not iterable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would want to replace

```
for i in len(arr)
```

with:

```
for i in range(len(arr))
```